# Same IP, same port and nmap scan gives different result. Why?

Tags: port, aws-fargate, nmap, port-scanning

I am getting different nmap scan result from AWS fargate cluster and my local Windows PC. The scaned IP and ports are the same. And I could not figure out why. Please help.

Here is the Windows PC scan result.

[image]

Here is the AWS fargate cluster scan result. Same command, same IP and same port.
[image]

I have no idea about how to debug next. Any idea is appropriated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have asked crazydomains to check my AWS cluster IPs and they said those IPs are not blocked.